# Mysql #2002 fail after updating macOS on macbook

Tags: mysql, macos

I have been developing website on my Mac for awhile already. Yesterday I updated my macOS version to v10.12.6 and after that mysql and phpmyadmin are not working properly with the following error:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 2002 - Connection refused — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

I have googled for so long and seen most of the answers are about the port 3306, but it is my original config for mysql. Can someone input more about what can it be wrong about?

UPDATE:
I found that on XAMPP it shows Mysql is running, however when I try to stop it, after saying it is trying to stop, it appeared to be running again. So it cannot be stopped somehow...

Comment: How do you update iOS on a Mac? iOS doesn't run on a Mac. macOS runs on a Mac.

Comment: Sorry I am using macbook pro right now. it is not IOS it should be macOS Sierra v10.12.6